# $code .= mb_substr($this->charset, $rnum, 1,'UTF-8');

Tags: php, captcha

$code .= mb_substr($this->charset, $rnum, 1,'UTF-8');

This code is working in my system, but when I'm uploading this onto my server it is showing an error.

Comment: What error does it give?

Comment: Is your program working with GD library?

Answer (score 1):

mbstring functions is not enabled by default, you need to compile PHP with mbstring support (or install a package that has mbstring support). More info: https://www.php.net/manual/en/mbstring.installation.php